# Error while pushing app to cloud foundry: FAILED Error processing app file: The directory is not empty

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am facing this error while pushing the spring app to the cloud foundry with the `cf push` command. Earlier it was being deployed just fine.

> D:\Documents\PredixApps\locomotive\locomotive-ingestion>cf push Using
>   manifest file
>   D:\Documents\PredixApps\locomotive\locomotive-ingestion\manifest.yml
>
> Updating app ehsan-locomotive-dataingestion-service in org username /
>   space dev as username... OK
>
> Uploading ehsan-locomotive-dataingestion-service... Uploading app
>   files from:
>   C:\Users\EHSAN~1.WAR\AppData\Local\Temp\unzipped-app070592951
>   Uploading 878K, 143 files Done uploading OK **FAILED Error processing
>   app files: remove
>   C:\Users\EHSAN~1.WAR\AppData\Local\Temp\unzipped-app070592951\lib: The
>   directory is not empty.**

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes there are issues on Windows where a lock on a file is not immediately released, or possibly other software (e.g. anti-virus software) has a lock on a file when the CLI tries to remove temporary files.
The CLI team is currently refactoring the `cf push` command and trying to reduce the number of temporary files created during the push process, which hopefully reduces the opportunity of this type of issue to occur.

Comment: is there any other way around this?

Comment: I wonder if setting TMP to a folder that is configured not to be scanned by anti-virus software before running `cf push` would work.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this same problem and **fixed this by upgrading my CloudFoundry CLI from version 6.25.0 to version 6.32.0.**

It was a bug with CloudFoundry CLI versions less than 6.32.0 per this reference https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/issues/1223